# Use Object detection model as feature extractor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api, transfer-learning

I have mask-rcnn model that was trained using Object Detection API to detect some objects. Now I have other task that needs to do regression on those images (and also other features). 
Is is possible to use the trained mask-rcnn model as feature extractor (similarly to how transfer learning works) and change the last layer (or layers) to other task?

Answer (score 1):

Mask r-cnn creates a shared feature map which is used for predictions on the RPN regions. With some slight tweaking to the object detection API, you could pull out the tensor containing the features for a given region. Normally these features are used for the box/mask prediction but you could use it for whatever else.

If you only need it to be a feature extractor (it remains frozen) this should work.
If you want to actually continue to train mask r-cnn based on further downstream results, this gets harder to do with the object detection API because you have to connect everything and modify a bunch of the TF training code. In this case you might consider building your own model, or a different approach depending on the problem.

Comment: Excessive self promotion may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help] and specially the last section of [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior): Avoid overt self-promotion. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).